# Regular expression for comments in Python re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to be able to identify comments by a regular expression using the `re` module in the standard library. The problem is that my line and multiline comments have the same start.

```
One-line comment:
#= this is a coment

some code here

#= this is a 
multiline comment =#
```

and I've been trying to get one (or more) regular expressions to be able to capture both of them. I've got `r'(#=)[\w ]*'` for the single line comment, but I've been unsuccessful for the multiline comment.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: seems like you should redesign how your comments work -- it's impossible to tell them apart

Comment: Couldn't something like `(#=.*\n.*=#(\b|\n|$))|(#=.*\n)` work for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has already been pointed out in the comments that this syntax is not ideal.
You can however parse your comments using negative lookahead:

```py
import re
s = """uniline comment:
#= this is a coment

some code here

#= this is a 
multiline comment =#

#=single comment at the end"""

pattern = re.compile(r'#=(?:(?!#=).)*?=#|#=.*?(?=\n|$)', re.DOTALL)
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(result)
```

- `#=(?:(?!#=).)*?=#`captures everything between `#=` and the next `=#` (multiline comment). We exclude `#=` to avoid capturing single line comments in our multiline match.
- `#=.*?(?=\n|$)` captures single line comments (`$` ensures single line comments are captured even at the end of the file)

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQTAmP/1)